# how can i create a traffic app using html5 for android platform

Tags: html, mobile, cordova

I am creating a mobile app using Phonegap, HTML5. This will target the Android devices.
this app should be able to feed traffic updates to users with the aide of notifications too 
is there anyone who has done such project and can guide me in doin such an app, ny recommendations would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a push notification plugin
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

here is an article on doing that

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/android-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html

You could also do the opposite pull using ajax from where ever. Here is an example using jquery ajax call.

```
function sendToServer(request, onSuccess) {
    LOG("sendToServer - " + request);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  ServiceHandlerURL + request,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: onSuccess,
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                LOG("Request URL Error: " + xhr.responseText + " | " + status + " | " + error);
           if (error != ""){
               navigator.notification.alert("An Error occurred. May be due to loss of internet connection. Error: " + xhr.responseText + " | " + error);}
                // navigator.app.exitApp(); // ?? what to do ??
           }
    });
}
```